# Proving the Value of a Unique Infinitely Nested Radical

Tags: sequences-and-series, nested-radicals

Math Stack Exchange!

I am trying to figure out how to find value of the infinitely nested radical

$$x = \sqrt{2^0 + \sqrt{2^2 + \sqrt{2^4 + \sqrt{2^8 + \ldots}}}}$$

I have already established that this expression converges based on [Herschfeld's Convergence Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_radical#Herschfeld%27s_convergence_theorem), but I am now interested in proving the specific value to which it converges.

Here is the proof that it converges:
Let $a_n = 2^{2^n}$. Then we have
$$ a_n^{2^{-n}} = (2^{2^n})^{2^{-n}} = 2^{2^n \cdot 2^{-n}} = 2^1 = 2 $$

In other words, for all $n$, $ a_n^{2^{-n}} = 2 $, which means the supremum of $ a_n^{2^{-n}} $ is 2 by Herschfeld's Convergence Theorem.

Thank you for any help!!

Comment: Can you precisely _define_ your quantity of nested radicals?

Comment: I suppose it should be formally defined by a sequence of functions $f_i:[0, \infty)\rightarrow [0,\infty)$ for $i \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$ by $f_1(x) = \sqrt{a_1+x}$, $f_2(x) = f_1(\sqrt{a_2+x})$, and so on, so $f_{i+1}(x)=f_i(\sqrt{a_{i+1}+x})$ for $i \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$. Then we want to know for which $x \in [0,\infty)$ can we ensure $\lim_{i\rightarrow\infty}f_i(x)$ exists and is finite. Perhaps the Herschfeld theorem answers this question.

Comment: If the next root after $2^8$ includes a $2^{16}$, then the outermost root should include a $2^1$ and not $2^0$ to be consistent. How are your terms defined?

Answer (score 5):

$x^2=1+\sqrt{2^2+\sqrt{2^4+\sqrt{2^8+...}}}=1+2\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+...}}}=1+2u$

Now notice that $u^2=1+u$ so by solving this this quadratic you get $u=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ and finally $x^2=1+2\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}=2+\sqrt{5}$

so $x=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{5}}\approx2.06$